# Oracle View loop on specific tables only

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I got many tables of which some end with digits (date).

Due to technical reasons I had to create a view on every table (just a workaround)

The current state is something like:

```sql
begin
  for i in (select table_name 
              from   user_tables 
              where  table_name like 'XXX_%'
             )
  loop
    execute immediate 'CREATE VIEW '||replace(i.TABLE_NAME,'XXX_','YYY_')||' AS SELECT * FROM '||i.TABLE_NAME;
  end loop;             
end;
/
```

All it does is creating views for every table which begins with 'XXX_'. Its almost what I need.

But now, sometimes tablenames look like "XXX_tablename_20210302", which is a manual backup.

Its not always 8 digits (date), sometimes shorter, soemtimes longer numbers. I would like to avoid all tables, which do have numbers in the end of the tablename (from right to left till first "_" checkup, its a number maybe?)

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Im kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with `regexp_like`:

```
create table xxx_t ( c1 int );
create table xxx_t_20210401 ( c1 int );

select table_name from user_tables
where  regexp_like ( table_name, '^XXX_.*[^0-9]+$' );

TABLE_NAME   
XXX_T
```

This finds all the tables that

- Start with XXX_ `XXX_`
- Followed by any characters `.*`
- That do **not** end with a digit `[^0-9]+$`

Comment: Hey, regex solution sound very helpful.

Your example did exclude all the tables which end with an digit. 

Thank you.

But I got some tables, which do end with a digit, but also do contain letters,
like: "TABLE_NAME_WSTVAL01". That table got excluded (my bad). Is there any possibility to exclude only tables which contain only digits after the last "_" (underline)? (variable numbers of underlines in table names).

Thanks in advance, and thank for the answer already. WIll dig into regex more now.

Comment: Just modify the regex to suit your requirements; you can use a site like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to check it's matching what you want